# db.Entry().CurrentValues.SetValues() remove my existing raw in Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

When i try to update table with currentvalues.setvalues() it is removed my existing row in ef in c# .net

```
var oldItem = db.ClaimDetail.FirstOrDefault(w => w.id == objParam.id );

if (oldItem != null)
{
   newItem.id = oldItem.id;
   db.Entry(oldItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(newItem);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
else
{
   MyEntity.Add(newItem);
}
```

It should update raw not removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Istead of this

```
db.Entry(oldItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(newItem);
```

use this

```
db.Entry(newItem).State = EntityState.Modified;
```